# Find limits of 2 sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have 2 sequences I have to find the limit of. But I'm not sure if I've proven this correct enough or if there's a better way to do so.

(a) $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\frac{n^2+(-1)^n}{5n^2+3n+1}$

(b) $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\frac{a^n+2b^n}{3a^n+5b^n}$ , for $a,b \gt 0$

So for (a) I have that since $(-1)^n$ is bounded, it is irrelevant for large n. Also, (I don't know the correct term for this) since $n^2$ is dominant compared to $n$, for very large $n$, the limit is basically $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $\frac{n^2}{5n^2}$ $= 1/5$.

I don't know how to write this correctly since this seems quite informal and not proven.

for (b) I'm not quite sure. First I tried factoring something out but I did not get very far. Now I used $c$ $=$ $a^n+2b^n$. This results in $\frac{c}{3c-b^n}$. But that's where I'm stuck. How do i proceed from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one to formalize use that

$$\frac{n^2+(-1)^n}{5n^2+3n+1}=\frac{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}}{5+\frac3n+\frac1{n^2}}$$

for the second one we have

$$\frac{a^n+2b^n}{3a^n+5b^n} =\frac{\left(\frac ab\right)^n+2}{3\left(\frac ab\right)^n+5}$$

then consider the cases $a>b$, $a=b$ and $a<b$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should've realised that it's much easier if I just divide by $n^2$

Comment: @23408924 Yes the first one is a standard way, for the second one it is more tricky. You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To justify your answer for a) divide all the terms by $n^{2}$ and the take the limit.

If $a>b$ divide all the terms by $a^{n}$. You see that the limit is $\frac  1 3$ (since $(\frac b a)^{n} \to 0$). If $a<b$ divide by $b^{n}$ to see that the limit is  $\frac  2 5$. If $a=b$ then the limit is $\frac {1+2} {3+5}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I don't think I would've come up with the idea for (b).